# Access allowed to a DispatcherObject from background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I thougt I understood how DispatcherObject is working when reading some tutorials, but got confused when I used it.
This is my program :

```
namespace DispatcherObjectDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Foo foo;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.foo = new Foo();
        }

        private void Parallel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task task = new Task(() => ChangeFoo());
            task.Start();
        }

        private void ChangeFoo()
        {
            // Protect from accessing to foo in background thread
            if (this.foo.CheckAccess())
            {
                this.foo = new Foo();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Foo : DispatcherObject
    {
        public string Name
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is to protect accessing to the foo object.
CheckAccess() is working as describer and prevent from assigning new reference to foo object.
My understanding if that if I do not protect my code I will have InvalidOperationException.

But when I removed it to give it a try, it worked with no Exception.

```
private void ChangeFoo()
{
    this.foo = new Foo();
}
```

Any explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
private void ChangeFoo()
{
    this.foo = new Foo();
}
```

on a task pool thread should not throw any exception. You are simply creating a new object and assigning it to a field.

You are referring to `InvalidOperationException`, and it is correct that a call to `DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the method is called on a thread that is not the dispatcher thread. However, calling `new Foo()` will not call `VerifyAccess` so you get no exception.

If you want the "invalid" code to throw an exception you should call `VerifyAccess` instead of `CheckAccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, 
But what about thread affinity :

> ... this is known as thread affinity, meaning you can only use a WPF
>   object on the thread on which it was created. Using it on other
>   threads will cause a runtime exception to be thrown...

My undertanding is that WPF objects created un UI thread can only be used un UI thread, calling them from background thread will throw an exception.